# NetBeans IDE, set command line arguments and run as main project, however, nothing is showing

Tags: java, netbeans, command-line, program-entry-point, args

I'm new to Java and is trying to learn the command line arguments using NetBeans IDE. Below is the code I used to test command line arguments.

```
public class Echo {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        for (String s: args) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

I went to Project --> Properties --> Run --> and type the arguments (i.e. a b c) next to "Arguments", I run the project from: run -- > run main project. However, no command line arguments were printed out? Why is this happening?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the big green arrow to run your project, or right-click on the project itself and select "Run.." from the menu.

If you use Shift-F6 ("Run File") it won't supply the command line arguments.  Those are for the project only.

Comment: It worked when I tried it.  Make sure you're running the right project, and you didn't add the command line parameters to another project that you have open.

Comment: yes you are right, I did not place the code in the right file (even though it is in the right folder) Thank you very much for your help. I have up voted and accepted your answer =)